# what does this line of syntax mean in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, syntax

this is a quick question, Im translating a program that's in C++ to C, and I saw this line of code,

```
for (int v : adj[u]) {
```

referenced in this article: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-shortest-paths-between-given-source-and-destination-in-an-undirected-graph/)

and I am not really sure what it does. I tried googling it and got results for range based for loops in C++, but cannot find anything that has this exact syntax and what it means. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: The missing piece is probably that `adj` is some sort of container of containers, which makes `adj[u]` a container that can be the range of a range-based for loop. Without knowing more about `adj` and `adj[u]` we can't really be more detailed.

Comment: All examples have exactly that syntax: it is `for (<declaration> : <expression>)`. If you don't understand `adj[u]`, look at the declaration of `adj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very simple for loop that iterates over the elements of adj[u], going 1 by 1.